# Concentration of Gaussian random matrices

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

I know that if $X$ be a random matrix distributed as $N(0,I_n)$, then $\frac{1}{n}X^TX$ is concentrated around the identity matrix. Does any body know the probability of $P(||\frac{1}{n}X^TX-I||<\delta)$?

Comment: A relatively recent paper by Vershynin (arxiv/abs/1004.3484) shows how to answer this question. He's mainly interested in asymptotics, but working through the proof of Proposition 2.1 would give you the result you want.

Comment: Another approach that would be looser yet would be probably a bit easier to compute is to apply Tropp's matrix concentration inequalities and bound the norm of a Gaussian vector with high probability. See Section 1.6.3 of arxiv/abs/1501.01571 for this.